# Passing in Command Line Arguments to C# .NET app Without Using Manifest File Inside a UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, command-line-arguments

I have a UWP app that I am developing that launches another application, which in turn launches a bat file, which does certain tasks, in order to not block the UI thread, while having enough permissions to do the tasks. The EXE I'm trying to launch is a separate .NET framework app that is in the same SLN, but a different project, in an app package project. However, the second C# app that the UWP app is launching requires command line arguments that may as often as the user of the app decides, so they can't be hard-coded into the manifest file, and using the following command:

```
await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync("ArgumentGroupName");
```

Is there an alternative to the above command that allows for parameters to be passed in, while changing the parameter value is available at every launch? I've googled for days without finding any topic on this apart from one comment on an SO post that I can't find that says that it can be done without using the app's manifest file. I am using the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 with the latest .NET Framework (4.8) and Windows SDK (Windows 2004-compatible). The second C# app runs using the .NET Framework and the main UWP app uses the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 0):

> Passing in Command Line Arguments to C# .NET app Without Using Manifest File Inside a UWP App

For your requirement, you could pass the launcher parameter with [`LocalSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings?view=winrt-19041). Store the parameter in the UWP client and retrieve value from launcher, then call process start with retrieved paramete.

For example

**UWP Client**

```
private async void btnClick_Parameters(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
    {
        // store command line parameters in local settings
        // so the Lancher can retrieve them and pass them on
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["parameters"] = "command parameter";

        await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync("Parameters");
    }
}
```

**Launcher**

```
string parameters = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["parameters"] as string;
Process newProcess = Process.Start(rootPath + @"WPF\WPF.exe", parameters);
```

For more detail please refer stanfen's blog **UWP with Desktop Extension – Part 2**

Comment: I should clarify this more in the question, but I don't think using processes will work. The EXE I'm trying to launch is a separate .NET framework app that is in the same SLN, but a different project, in an app package project. I don't think .NET has access to the same settings file, if I can recall correctly. Using processes I don't think worked due to the sandbox nature of UWP, but I might be mistaken. I have been using the alternative method that I have mentioned in the question ever since I asked a question about it yesterday. A bonus would be having an async method to use.

Comment: This is so the UI thread doesn't get blocked, but the code that changes the UI elements can also run without being "marshmalled by another thread". I don't need parameters for the second app, I just need to be able to pass information from the UWP app to the .NET one (as arguments, if possible).

Comment: So, you need add the launched app in the `ParameterGroup` like the blog said.